# Keep only the caption description in small caps but lower case Figure x and Table x

Tags: fonts, captions

Currently I use the package `caption` to have everything in caption using `\usepackage[font=sc]{caption}`

Result is the following :

FIGURE 3.1: TITLE DESCRIPTION

However, I would like to have :

Figure 3.1: TITLE DESCRIPTION.

How could I do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[textfont=sc]{caption}` instead.